# NameError in dictionary-based switch case

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I have no experience with python, so I thought I'd start looking into it for my new hobby. I'm having an issue when it comes to a switch case, which python doesn't have, after googling I found most use a dictionary style method which you can see below. It's a small .py file I'm building to replicate an ATM style system, just to get me familiar with all of python's options.

```
while True:
    print ("Who are you?")
    name = input().lower()

    if re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", name):
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid name')


print('Hello ' + name)

print("Please enter your PIN " + name)
pin = input()


accounts = {"stephen" : stephen,
           "Dean" : Dean,
           "Jennifer" : Jennifer,
           "Liam" : Liam,
           "Billie" : Billie,
           "Decky" : Decky,
           "Joel" : Joel,
}

accounts[name]()

def stephen():
    if pin == 1234:
        print("Pin Accepted")
    else:
        print("Wrong PIN")

def Dean():
    if pin == 1344:
        print("Pin Accepted")
    else:
        print("Wrong PIN")
```

Now the problem is that when I get to the enter pin section, it comes back with an error saying the following:

> options = {"stephen" : stephen, NameError: name 'stephen' is not defined

Any ideas what it could be? looking at the example it seems I have everything right, but I couldn't find an answer from googling the specific error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point where you get the error because you try to use `stephen`, it's not defined yet. Create that dictionary *after* the function has been defined.

Comment: thank you very much! i didn't know it goes line by line, im still familiar with the main method style in c#. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Python is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), which means that the code is executed by the interpreter line by line without previously compiling. So the function `stephen` is not defined when you try to enter it into the dictionary because it's only defined later in the script. Define the function `stephen` prior to entering it into the dictionary and your script will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
accounts = {"stephen" : stephen,
           "Dean" : Dean,
           "Jennifer" : Jennifer,
           "Liam" : Liam,
           "Billie" : Billie,
           "Decky" : Decky,
           "Joel" : Joel,
}
```

1) the values in your `accounts` dictionary cause the error.  no matter variables or functions, you have to define them before use.

2) remove the last comma in your `account` dictionary

An easy sample is here:

```
>>> mydict ={"a":A}  # A is not defined, will raise Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
>>> mydict ={"a":"A"}  # A is string here, it is okay
>>> A = "A"  # declares A and assigns value to it
>>> mydict ={"a":A}  # good now.
```

Comment: What do you mean if they are variable names? They're the names of his functions below. Also, why remove that comma?